# write.table - user defined function R

Tags: r, function, csv

My function is as below. I would like my function to take parameters such that I can name the file that I wanted exported as a csv.

```
my_function <- function(Part_1, Part_2){
  write.table(a$part_1, "Part_1.csv", sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
  write.table(a$part_2, "Part_2.csv", sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
}
```

When I execute this function as below:

```
my_function(Part_1 = alpha, Part_2 = beta)
```

I want the two files to be exported with the names of the files as "alpha.csv" and "beta.csv." However, it gets named as "Part_1.csv" and "Part_2.csv."

I have also tried putting alpha is quotes - but that didn't work.

It would be great if I could get your help! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Pass `Part_1` and `Part_2` as strings (ie `my_function("alpha", "beta")`) then replace the `"Part_1.csv"` in your function with `paste0(Part_1, ".csv")`